# Question about turtlebot _robot.launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, in *robot.launch, I'm confused in a sentence: ".../robots/$(arg base)_$(arg stacks)*$(arg 3d_sensor).urdf.xacro'" />". Can anyone give me a detailed explanation of this sentence? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156631/question-about-turtlebot-_robot.launch/) by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you know, `arg` means an argument. As @dornhege also say, you have to choose a base of turtlebot model create, kobuki or roomba. You can check some urdf.xacro files in `/turtlebot_description/robots`.

```
create_circles_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro
create_circles_kinect.urdf.xacro
kobuki_hexagons_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro
kobuki_hexagons_kinect.urdf.xacro
roomba_circles_asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro
roomba_circles_kinect.urdf.xacro
```

```
$(arg base)_$(arg stacks)_$(arg 3d_sensor).urdf.xacro
```

You will understand the meaning if you look at above description.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `_robot.launch` is generic and accepts different turtlebot variants that can be set via args. This just selects the correct URDF. Base is Kobuki or Create base. Stacks are the plates (round/hexagonal), and 3d sensor is kinect or xtion.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2014-04-23**:
Thanks, and I found that "value="$(optenv..." does the selection function.